# How to create search box and show the value in another form in c#?

Tags: c#

I am creating a software for car dealing in windows form c#. i want a search box in which the customer can be searched by Id and all the details of that customer be shown in another form.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 and using local database to save the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as implementing a searchbox, a simple approach is to use a standard [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netcore-3.1) with an accompanying [Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button?view=netcore-3.1) to search for the text provided once it has been entered.

Here is an example of how you could handle this input using a TextBox named *textbox*  depends on exact how your database / data structure is set up.

Let's say you had your customer's data in a [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netcore-3.1) where the key for each set of details is a *string* representing that customer's ID number, and the value stored is an instance of a class *Details* which contains whatever information about that customer. ie, adding to this table would look like...

```
customerDetailsTable.Add("0123456", new Details(string Name, int age, .......))
```

The code could to search through this using the textbox and button could look something like this:

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // <-- click event for button
{
    if(textBox.Text.Length > 0) // <-- if something has been entered to search
    {
        Details customerDetails = customerDetailsTable[textBox.Text]; // search table
        if(customerDetails != null) // <-- if an entry exists for a customer of this ID   
        {
           using(DetailsPage page = new DetailsPage(customerDetails))
           {
              page.ShowDialog();
           }
        }
        else // <-- if NO entry exists for a customer of this ID
        {
           // ALERT USER THAT NO CUSTOMER EXISTS FOR THIS ID (via MessageBox, however)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the example above, if the object containing the details for that customer ID is found, it is passed through a constructor to a new form I named DetailsPage. This is the form you will create to display these details, taking one *Details* parameter in the form's constructor, such as...

```
public partial class DetailsPage : Form
{
    private Details deets;

    public DetailsPage(Details d)
    {
        deets = d;

        // however you plan on displaying the details
    }
}
```